# Program fails normally, but not in Valgrind

Tags: c, memory, valgrind

I've experienced this issue while debugging my application written in C11. I read other stack posts related, but none of them solved my problem. My code contains a 'safe malloc' implementation which looks like:

```
void *try_malloc(size_t size) {
  void *mem = malloc(size);
  if (!mem) { perror("Error: unable to allocate memory"); exit(1); }
  return mem;
}
```

I compile it with:
`gcc -Wall -Wextra -std=c11 -ggdb -o main`
Then when I run it with: `./main < inp.in`, it apparently has a problem with memory and outputs "Error: unable to allocate memory: Cannot allocate memory" and exits with code 1. When I run it with `valgrind ./main < inp.in`, valgrind reports no warnings or errors, reports than no memory leaks are possible and the program prints the correct output.
I wrote a simple testing script for convenience:

```
$ cat ttest.sh
./main < inp.in
```

When I run valgrind like: `valgrind ./ttest.sh`, the same problem as above occurs again, this is "Error: unable to allocate memory: Cannot allocate memory", but valgrind is incapable of producing a meaningful trace and gives me no information about why the problem occurs. `Inp.in` is a large file and my program should use a lot of memory to process it. For smaller input files no memory errors occur. My environment in Debian run in WSL2.

- How can I debug it?
- Why the program ran in Valgrind works correctly?
- How to setup Valgrind so that I can reproduce the allocation error?
- Might it be a race condition somehow? (though I don't use any threading etc., the code has nothing asynchronous)
- Might it be that WSL limits memory for sub-processes? How to check it?

@EDIT:
The problem is suppressed by Valgrind's effect on the program's execution environment. I will try to find how exactly Valgrind affects the env to try to reproduce the problem and possibly provide the MRE

Comment: Code is incomplete. Please provide a [complete minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). That is, show the exact and complete code that can reproduce the problem. For example, how do we know that the function isn't being called with an overly large `size` value?

Comment: You can run in a debugger and put a breakpoint on the `perror`. You may also want to print `size` to make sure it has a reasonable value.

Comment: Regarding valgrind, when you run the shell script in valgrind it won't check your program unless you use `--trace-children=yes`.

Comment: @kaylum I'm aware that I should provide CMRE, but I can't even properly reproduce the problem, let alone find its source without providing the full source code which  is a few kLOCs large

Comment: @interjay that's very helpful! I used this flag to find out that my program under `valgrind ./ttest.sh` has the mentioned memory problem, but under `valgrind --trace-chldren=yes ./ttest.sh` it works properly again. im confused.

Comment: 1. make a copy of the source code. 2. delete parts of it until the problem doesn't occur. 3. put the last part you deleted back in. 4. repeat until there are no more parts you can delete (every part is essential to causing the problem) 5. you've probably figured out the answer by the point. If not, post on Stack Overflow

Comment: Errors that seem to disappear when you try to debug your program are usually related to undefined behavior. I guess the value of `size` results from undefined behavior and is a very big number when you run your program without trying to debug it. When running with `valgrind` the memoy layout may be different or uninitialized variables might get different values resulting in different behavior of your program.

Comment: Valgrind replaces whatever malloc functions you were using, and does its own memory management. Hance if you have behaviour that depends on glibc uninitialized memory then you might get some different behaviour with Valgrind uninitialized memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem - the bug was in my code (I forgot to update a pointer after reallocating the data structure which it pointed to). However, I can't answer the question of why the program didn't fail in Valgrind